# Understanding array of strings C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C, I can declare an array of strings like :

`char *hey[] = {"hi", "hello", "bye"};`

And then I can just iterate over it and print the elements using `hey[0]` and `hey[1]`..

How does this work? Why don't I need to do `*hey[0]` to deference it??

Comment: I think this was downvoted (not by me, for the record) because although it is a fair question, it is a very elementary question and there are a lot of resources available for you to find the answer without having someone hand it to you custom-written.

Answer (score 1):

Because `*hey[0]` will give you the first character in the string `hey[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dereference `hey[0]`, you do indeed need to use `*hey[0]` to dereference it. The thing is that you're not dereferencing it.

In C, saying "a string" is usually the same as saying "a pointer to some characters with a 0 at the end." So a `char*` is a string already. There's nothing to dereference.

(This is not entirely correct, but it's close enough)

Again, you *could* dereference it if you wanted to. `*hey[0]` would be 'h'.

Answer (score 1):

`*hey[0]` is de-referencing twice.

As people have explained a string is essentially a pointer to the start of an array of characters, usually terminating in a null character `'\0'`.

An array is also essentially just a pointer to the start of a list of elements.

Maybe this will help explain:

```
char *hey[] = {"hi", "yellow", "bye"};
char **pPointer = hey;
char one, two, three;

one = *(*pPointer+1);
two = **(pPointer+1);
three = *(pPointer[1]);
```

You will notice that I can just replace hey with `pPointer`, which is just a `char**` rather than a `char*` array.  A pointer to a series of pointers (a pointer to an array).

`one = 'i'` - I am de-referencing `pPointer` once, getting to the first string `"hi"` then +1 takes me one element along to the character `'i'`.

`two = 'y'` - `pPointer+1` takes me to the next element in the 'string' array, to the pointer to the string "yellow", de-referencing this would give me the string "yellow" then de-referencing that gives me the character `'y'`.  In your case, doing pPoin

`three = 'y'` - This is just to show that  `*(pPointer+1)` is the same as `pPointer[1]`.

This is fairly basic, however can be a bit confusing at first, I suggest you play around with pointers, arrays and strings until you feel comfortable with these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Because the C programming language doesn't have a native string type, what you have is a pointer to an array of character arrays (which are all '\0', aka null, terminated). Your example of `*hey[0]` is perfectly valid, and actually points to the letter 'h' in "hi".